# Can't refresh a picture inside a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm trying to change a picture inside my tableview. I'm using `[myTableView reloadData];` in another method (that is firing up) to refresh my `TableView` and I can see that other elements in the tableview are refreshing but the image stays the same. What Am I missing?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *lblName;
    UIImageView *checkMark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 0, 30, 50)];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 1, 260, 70)];
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x000000, 0.3);
        backgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;        

        checkMark.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"V.png"];
        checkMark.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        checkMark.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [backgroundView addSubview:checkMark];
        [checkMark release];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
        [backgroundView release];
    }
    if (something)
    {
        checkMark.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"halfleft.png"];
        NSLog(@"something was done");
    }
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: the last '}' before 'if(something)' should be moved right under 'cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];'

Comment: Why is that? I don't want to keep adding subviews unless the cell is nil.

Comment: But you need new image to appear on same cell rigth? therefore you  just to create only cell if it is nil. Every other thing should be outside (cell == nil) block.

Comment: If I put it outside the cell == nil everything becomes slow and unresponsive after a few UITableView scrolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reloadData correctly calls this method.

Your problem is simple, the pointer on "checkMark" isn't good in the case the cell is "reused". Do something like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIView *backgroundView;
    UIImageView *checkMark;
    if (cell == nil) {

        checkMark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 0, 30, 50)];
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 1, 260, 70)];
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x000000, 0.3);
        backgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        backgroundView.tag = 555;

        checkMark.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"V.png"];
        checkMark.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        checkMark.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        checkMark.tag = 666;
        [backgroundView addSubview:checkMark];
        [checkMark release];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
        [backgroundView release];
    } else {
        backgroundView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:555];
        checkMark = (UIImageView *)[backgroundView viewWithTag:666];
    }
    if (something)
    {
        checkMark.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"halfleft.png"];
        NSLog(@"something was done");
    }
    return cell;

}
```

But, you should do something more simple (less subviews if possible. OR subclass UITableViewCell to have a pointer on the checkmark ;-)

Comment: Your code works but there's a repetitive response. I can see the `checkMark.image` is also added to other cells too. also, can you please explain what's the tag used to here?

Comment: I don't know how your code should work. But avoid any .image in the cell creation (in if (cell == nil){}). The tags allows you to identificate the views and so you can find them when they are reused. So remove any "dynamic" content from the if(cell == nil) and do it in the code after :-)

Comment: The problem is that if I add subviews outside cell == nil everything becomes slow and unresponsive after a few UITableView scrolls. Is that suppose to happen? Maybe it got something to do with the fact that I never release myTable in viewDidLoad (another problem I have..)

Comment: Don't create/add subviews them outside. But set text&images outisde, this shouldn't slow down too much your table scroll. This method (cellForRowAtIndexPath) is to create and reuse cells. But it allows too, to fill it with some content.

Comment: This is what I did in the original question. I created the subview inside the `cell == nil` and changed the picture outside but it didn't work.

Comment: yes because as I explained to you, the pointer to the imageView was wrong. if you do like I wrote, it's fine. BUT you may have a little glitch in some cases where I can't help you without your full code. Try to understand the whole thing a bit better and you'll won't do the same error again ;)